# How to fix "package system is broken" after upgrading to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, package-management

I can no longer remove or install any software or perform any updates. I got this error message after I upgraded to 12.04:

```
The package system is broken
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpam-winbind: Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.3 is installed
                Depends: winbind (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1 is installed
                Depends: samba-common (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.3 is installed
winbind: Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.3 is installed
         Depends: samba-common (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1) but 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.3 is installed
```

I'm a new user so I have no idea what to do with this error message.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you tried the suggestions starting in the second line of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands they will solve it:

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
 sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: What if sudo apt-get install -f results in another error?